# Getting Exception :org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: selenium, gradle, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on selenium-Cucumber-Gradle project I see that when I execute my UI Automation scripts with chrome browser it just open the browser and even I could the see the url is shown up in the browser address bar but within 2 seconds it exits with a exception as shown below. Any advise here would be greatly appreciated. I am using the latest chrome browser and chrome driver

**Output Results
=============**

```
    Given User navigates to the Rlbs website # RLbys_CardPage_Ui_Step_Test.navigates_to_the_RLby_s_website()
      org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-4', revision: 'c2d955b49e'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 85.0.4183.83, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa..., userDataDir: C:\Users\xxx~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOption
s: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61816}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileIntera
ctability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: e88071b72a89d636e000150881ccb44a
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:196)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:129)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:161)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:282)
        at com.pros.HALbrands.test.stepdefinition.HALCardPage_Ui_Step_Test.user_navigates_to_the_HALRLby_s_website(HALRLbyCardPage_Ui_Step_Test.java:40)
        at ?.User navigates to the HALRLby website(file:src/test/resources/featurefile/HALRLbyCardPage_Ui.feature:5)
```

May i know what might be issue for which is exception is thrown.

## Please find the code snippet below:

### Feature File Code

Feature: Google Search Functionality

Scenario: Validate google search functionality
Given User navigates to the google website
When  User enters text as Cards in search text field

### Step Defenition

```
 public class Test1
 {

    @Given("User navigates to the google website")
    public void user_navigates_to_the_Google_s_website() {
 
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        
    }

}
```

------------------------------Invoking Browser Below --------------------------

```
public WebDriver standAloneStepUp(BrowserType bType) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver;
        
        try {
            oLog.info(bType);

            switch (bType) {

            case CHROME:
                //ChromeBrowser chrome = ChromeBrowser.class.newInstance();
                //WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                System. setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                return driver;

            case FIREFOX:
//              FirefoxBrowser firefox = FirefoxBrowser.class.newInstance();
//              WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                System. setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\driver\\geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                //driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox.getFirefoxOptions());
                return driver;


         default:
                throw new NoSutiableDriverFoundException(" Driver Not Found : " + ObjectRepo.reader.getBrowser());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            oLog.equals(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should **at least** provide the code you're executing. Based on the provided error one can only assume what the problem is.
However, based on the error `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` I assume your page address is incorrect. Check out the internet for more details on this error and you just might find a possible resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure it out what was the issue. Actually this happens when you are accessing the site which is not yet open to public.
So got it resolved in two steps :

- First I connected to client VPN
- Though connected to client VPN but still I was getting this same issue so went and added few lines related to clinet url along with ip address in host file

Path of host file : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host

```
10.104.0.38 ida-oa.dev.dp-prv.halproducts.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com

10.104.0.38 order-inte-service-dev.dev.dp-prv.halproducts.astus.cloudapp.azure.com

<ip adress > <client env  url >
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case on **Bamboo** build was failing, but on my local machine it was working well. So after a lot of research.

To run it on CI/CD my `https://example.com` was not whitelisted. If you have admin access please do it yourself or ask it from DevOps